# Bash shell script error sh: [: missing `]'

Tags: git, bash, shell, unix, bitbucket

**Aim:**

I'm trying to create a useful shortcut for initializing a git repo locally, and simultaneously creating a remote repo origin on bitbucket or github. This function is added to my `.bashrc` file in my home directory.

**Here is the bash function (which yields an error):**

```
function initg() {
 # Defaults to bitbucket API
 local API="https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/"
 local DATA="name=$3&description=$4&is_private=true&scm=git"
 local REMOTE="ssh://git@bitbucket.org/$2/$3"

 # Use github if specified
 if [ "$1" == "gh" ]; then
      API="https://api.github.com/user/repos"
      DATA='{"name":"$3", "description": "$4"}'
      REMOTE="git@github.com:$2/$3"
 fi

 if [ -z "$API" ] || [ -z "$DATA" ] || [ -z "$REMOTE" ] || [ -z "$2" ]
 then
      echo "A parameter is missing or incorrect"
 else
      curl -X POST -u $2 ${API} -d ${DATA}
      git init
      git add .
      git commit -m "Created repo"
      git remote add origin $REMOTE
      git push -u origin master
 fi
}
```

**The error:**

```
username@COMPUTER-NAME /path/to/local/repo
$ initg gh username bash_test desc
sh: [: missing `]'
sh: [: missing `]'
Enter host password for user 'username':
```

**My Question:**

First, where is my error? Secondly, how might I improve the control flow or structure of this script to achieve the stated goals?

Comment: Try `bash -x initg gh username bash_test desc` to see which lines trigger the error. And use the `[[ ]]` syntax instead of `[]` (as [in one of my scripts](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/sbin/check_all_diff) for instance)

Comment: The fact that it's saying `sh:` seems to imply that it's running in either a proper variant of `sh`, or `bash` in POSIX compliance mode, which could be exacerbating the issue. In addition, it's a function so while the code above looks ok, you may actually be invoking the wrong function because it's already sourced

Comment: Try putting the above code followed by the command to trigger the function in a separate file, say `test.sh` and invoke `bash -x test.sh`.

Comment: `$3` and `$4` are not being expanded when you set the value of `DATA` when `$1` equals "gh", since they occur in single quotes. This may cause a problem when you later use `$DATA` unquoted in the call to `curl`, or possibly (because of the `[`-related error) when you use it with `-z`.

Answer (score 40):

I've got that kind of error because I didn't use space before ] ex:

```
if [ "$#" -ne 2]; then
```

instead of

```
if [ "$#" -ne 2 ]; then
```

PS: I know this is an old question but it might do some help for someone :)

Answer (score 4):

I've run into such nonsense from bash several times (a bug?), and the way out was to replace `[ some-condition ]` by `test some-condition`

Answer (score 3):

### Update/Provisional Answer

Okay this is strictly speaking not an (informed) answer, however I have managed to resolve the issue.

**Debugging**

I ran the function and command in a separate dedicated script file, using the command `bash -x test.sh`suggested by devnull in the comments of the original post.

This yielded quite a lot of feedback in the shell. Here is what I believe to be the most critical feedback, before I aborted it.

```
username@COMPUTERNAME /d/test
$ bash -x test.sh
+ initg gh username bash_test desc
+ local API=https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/
+ local 'DATA=name=bash_test&description=desc&is_private=true&scm=git'
+ local REMOTE=ssh://git@bitbucket.org/username/bash_test
+ '[' gh == gh ']'
+ API=https://api.github.com/user/repos
+ DATA='{"name":"$3", "description": "$4"}'
+ REMOTE=git@github.com:username/bash_test
+ '[' -z https://api.github.com/user/repos ']'
+ '[' -z '{"name":"$3", "description": "$4"}' ']'
+ '[' -z git@github.com:username/bash_test ']'
+ '[' -z username ']'
+ curl -X POST -u username https://api.github.com/user/repos -d '{"name":"$3",' '"description":' '"$4"}'
+ Enter host password for user 'username':
```

**The Issue:**

So the issue seems to lie with the variable expression (below) where DATA is set. Firstly the arguments passed to the script, referenced by `$3` and `$4` cannot be interpolated within a single quoted string.

```
DATA='{"name":"$3", "description": "$4"}'
```

Also the spaces after the comma and second semi-colon strangely wrapped in single quotes breaking the string in several pieces, visible in the resulting failed curl call.

**Resolution**

So apart from using `[[ ]]` double square brackets instead of the original singular square brackets, I simply wrapped each interpolated variable with curly braces such as `${3}` and fixed the use of quotes and spaces in the DATA variable assignment (below):

```
DATA="{\"name\":\"${3}\",\"description\":\"${4}\"}"
```

**Post script**

I this answer can be improved, if anyone can extend on this answer that would be great. I'm confused as to why the `$DATA` variable used in the curl call resolved to `'{"name":"$3",' '"description":' '"$4"}'`

Comment: As you already wrote, quoting with ' and " works differently. For exact details, look at `man bash', section quoting. The most important part is that $ substitutions just do not happen within '. IMHO, DATA='{"name":"'$3'", "description":"'$4'"}' looks a bit nicer though :)

Answer (score 0):

To feed `DATA` variable, try this :

```
printf -vDATA '{"name":"%s", "description": "%s"}' $3 $4
echo "$DATA"
```